# PHP - I'm trying to parse the XML?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse the XML below so that I wind up with an array that looks like the sample included... I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the attributes inside of the tags to output the way I want it to...

**The XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a>
  <a i="A">
    <a i="0">
      <a i="0">20</a>
      <a i="1">10</a>
    </a>
    <a i="1">
      <a i="0">45</a>
    </a>
  </a>
  <a i="B">
      <a i="0">65</a>
  </a>
  <a i="C">95</a>
</a>
```

**The Array I want :: Note the added array elements**

```
array[A][0][0] = '20';
array[A][0][1] = '10';
array[A][1][1] = '45';
array[B][0] = '65';
array[C] = '20';

array(
        'A' => array(
                        '0' => array(
                                        0 => 20,
                                        1 => 10
                                    ),
                        '1' => array(
                                        0 => 45
                                    ),
        ),
        'B' => array(
                        0 => 65
                    ),
        'C' => '20'
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You would like to use SimpleXML.

You can find tutorial [here](http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/php-simplexml).

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do, I think you need to use SimpleXML. It stores the XML elements like an multidimensional array.
See here a [SimpleXML tutorial](http://www.coursesweb.net/php-mysql/php-simplexml)